# Can't get non-nullable feature to work on flutter

Tags: flutter

I've set my SDK to `>=2.10.0-0 <3.0.0` on `pubspec.yaml`, which is the minimum version the warning tells me to use, and then tried running both `Pub get` and `Pub upgrade` but nothing is happening.

Is there a step I'm missing?

Comment: Do you have more debug information (error traces etc..)? Did you switch to beta channel, which version of flutter and dart do you have?

Comment: @olibiaz There's no error, I just can't compile because it keeps giving me the error on non-nullable when I try to. Running flutter --version gets me Dart version 2.10.5 and Flutter version 1.22.6

Comment: when you run `flutter --version`, do you see that you are in beta channel? `Flutter 1.25.0-8.1.pre • channel beta, Dart 2.12.0 (build 2.12.0-133.2.beta` I think the null sound safety is still only in beta. So your Dart should be at least `2.12`

Comment: @olibiaz weird. The warning only told me to use 2.10.0-0 or higher. Switched to dev channel, upgraded and it started working. Can you create an answer so I can give you the correct answer tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably a problem of version. Currently, i think the null sound safety is only on the beta channel, so your Dart should be `2.12` or greater.

So you should have something like that:

```
> flutter --version

Flutter 1.25.0-8.1.pre • channel beta • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 8f89f6505b (2 months ago) • 2020-12-15 15:07:52 -0800
Engine • revision 92ae191c17
Tools • Dart 2.12.0 (build 2.12.0-133.2.beta)
```

Try upgrading your libraries and switch to beta channel:

```
flutter channel beta
```

More info here: [Null safety announcement](https://medium.com/flutter/announcing-dart-null-safety-beta-4491da22077a)